# Горизонтальные полосы у ячеек. Как убрать?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Как убрать горизонтальные полосы у ячеек. `border: none` - не работает, `border-collapse:collapse` - тоже. Отступ убирается если убрать у .window transform translate, но тогда блок уже не по центру стоит. Можно ли убрать как то этот отступ при использовании transform translate

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro";
  src: url(../fonts/gothampro.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham Pro bold";
  src: url(../fonts/gothampro_bold.ttf);
}


/* Window */

.window {
  width: max-content;
  height: auto;
  padding: 2.0833vw 2.864583vw 1.40625vw 2.864583vw;
  border-radius: 0.5208333333333334vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.window .header {
  font-size: 1.354167vw;
  color: #ebae0b;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro bold";
  text-align: center;
}

.window .light {
  color: #ffcc00;
}

.window .about {
  font-size: 0.8333333333333334vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro";
  align-self: flex-start;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 1vw 0 1.5vw 0;
  line-height: 1.2vw;
}

.window .choise {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.window input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 61px;
  border-radius: 0.5208333333333334vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8333333333333334vw;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro";
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.72917vw;
}

.window ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

body {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* BACKGROUND */

.bg::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('../img/bg4.png');
  filter: grayscale(1) saturate(0%) opacity(0.12);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 10% 45%;
}

.bg1::before {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 49% 64%;
}

.bg2::before {
  background-size: 180%;
  background-position: 49% 64%;
}

#f {
  color: #5da56c;
}


/* MENU */

.menu {
  margin: 0.5vw;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 23.4vw;
}

.menu_1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.260417vw;
}

.menu::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(169, 118, 118, 0.07);
}

.menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ff9600 0%, #ffcc00 100%);
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0.4vw 0 -0.5vw;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.6fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header header header ";
  /* border: 1px solid white; */
  width: 37.86458334vw;
  margin: 0.2864584vw 0.46875vw;
}

.item .table {
  margin: 0;
}

.item .table .column {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.table .column {
  font-size: 0.834vw;
  color: #ffca00;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro";
  text-align: center;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 1vw;
  /* border: 1px solid white;  */
}

.menu .active .column {
  color: #1a1919;
}

.table .column:nth-child(2) {
  padding: 0;
}

.one_item {
  background-color: #ffca00;
}

.menu .item {
  height: 2.5vw;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 0.8334vw;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro";
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.3864584vw 1vw;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0vw 1.2vw;
}

.menu .item_table {
  height: 2.5vw;
  background-color: #5da56c;
  font-size: 0.8334vw;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro";
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0.3864584vw 1vw;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0vw 1.2vw;
}

.menu .item2 {
  width: auto;
}

.menu .active {
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #ff9600 0%, #ffcc00 100%);
  color: #1a1919;
}

.active span {
  color: #1a1919 !important;
}

.menu .item:hover {
  background-color: rgba(62, 62, 62, 0.6);
}

.menu .item span {
  padding-right: 0.4vw;
  color: #ffcc00;
}

.menu .active span {
  color: #1a1919;
}

.color_text_active {
  color: #1a1919;
}


/* Buttons */

.btn {
  width: 7.2917vw;
  height: 2.447917vw;
  font-size: 0.78125vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro";
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0.2864583vw;
}

.success {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #5da56c 0%, #60c760 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.78125vw 0.250625vw rgba(71, 155, 65, 0.5);
}

.success:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.78125vw 0.250625vw rgba(71, 155, 65, 0.7);
}

.discard {
  display: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #913f3f 0%, #ca5555 100%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.78125vw 0.250625vw rgba(154, 65, 65, 0.5);
}

.discard:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0.78125vw 0.250625vw rgba(154, 65, 65, 0.7);
}


/* HIDE */

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.window_1 {
  display: none;
}

.window_2 {
  display: block;
}

.window_3 {
  display: none;
}

.window_4 {
  display: none;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  padding: 0 1vw;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tr td:first-of-type {
  border-top-left-radius: 1vw;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1vw;
}

tr td:last-of-type {
  border-top-right-radius: 1vw;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1vw;
}

.window_2 .item {
  min-width: 13vw;
}

.window_4 .column {
  font-size: 0.834vw;
  color: #ffca00;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Gotham Pro";
  padding: 0 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="window_2">
  <div class="window bg">
    <div id="header_1" class="header light">Панель управления главного</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <table>
        <tr class="item_table">
          <td>ggggg</td>
          <td>ggggg</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="choise">
      <div id="btn_success_2" class="btn success">Выбрать</div>
      <div id="btn_discard_2" class="btn discard">Закрыть</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Код в студию ...

Comment: Добавил код. Можете смотреть

Comment: @vovaVS: на скриншоте одно, а при запуске кода совсем другое.

Comment: Отступы то все равно видны =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, немного отредактировал .window

```
.window{
  width: max-content;
  height: auto;
  padding: 2.0833vw 2.864583vw 1.40625vw 2.864583vw;
  border-radius: 0.5208333333333334vw;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```